# Is there any way to use fscanf to read in the following white space?

Tags: c, scanf

The following will only read until the next white space occurs, excluding it

```
fscanf (list_in, "%s", keywords);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you could use a [character class](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007904975/functions/scanf.html):

```
fscanf( list_in, "%[^ \r\n\t]", keywords );
```

Of course, to avoid buffer overruns, you should always set a maximum length when reading strings with (f)scanf, as in:

```
char keywords[81];

fscanf( list_in, "%80[^ \r\n\t]", keywords );
```

---

Edit: If you want to *include* the trailing whitespace character in the string, you could read it separately into a `char` variable using a `%c` directive, and either process it that way or append it to the string:

```
char keywords[82], space;
int n;

fscanf( list_in, "%80[^ \r\n\t]%c", keywords, &space );

n = strlen( keywords );
keywords[n] = space;
keywords[n+1] = '\0';
```

(Of course, to be extra careful, you should also check the return value of `fscanf` to make sure you didn't, for example, hit the end of the input file.)

Comment: Thanks for taking a looka t thus, and if I understand correctly, your code will ignore spaces, newlines, tabs etc. ??
However i should have been more precise!, I require the word read into trhe file to be "int " as opposed to "int" which fscanf seems to acheive in any case, maybe i should manually check character by character?

Comment: You mean you want to _include_ the terminating whitespace character in the string, rather than _excluding_ it?

Comment: YES, exactly what i was looking for! I tried to upvote you but apparently I haven't enough rep! Cheers though!

Comment: Even if you can't upvote yet, you can ([and should](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)) still accept the answer if you like it by clicking the checkmark below the voting arrows.